# How find the number of zeros at the end of the sum $4^{5^6}+6^{5^4}$?

Tags: power-towers

The problem is to find the number of zeros at the end of the sum $4^{5^6}+6^{5^4}$.

I tried $2^{2 \cdot 5^6}+3^{5^4} \cdot 2^{5^4}=  2^{5^4}  \cdot (  2^{2 \cdot 5^6  -5^4}+    3^{5^4}  )$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following lemma, which can be proven by induction 'on $b$':

For any odd prime $p$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $p^a \mid\mid x-y$ and $p^b \mid\mid k$:

$p^{a+b} \mid\mid x^k-y^k$.

For this question we don't need the "strictly divides" in the conclusion, but in general this lemma is very useful.

$4^{5^6}+6^{5^4} = (4^{5^2})^{5^4}+6^{5^4} = (4^{5^2})^{5^4}-(-6)^{5^4}$ and $5 \mid 4^{5^2}-(-6)$ by Fermat's little theorem.

Therefore by the lemma $5^5 \mid 4^{5^6}+6^{5^4}$.

Combining with what you already have gives the number of zeros.

Comment: What's the difference between $||$ and $|$? And how do you read it?

Comment: $p^k \mid\mid x \Leftrightarrow p^k \mid x \wedge p^{k+1} \nmid x$.

Comment: @GFauxPas: Note also that the lemma is slightly different if $p$ is the special even prime $2$. In particular the conclusion would be $p^{a+b+1} \mid\mid x^k-y^k$ if I remember correctly.

Comment: @GFauxPas: Read "$\mid$" as "divides" and "$\mid\mid$" as "strictly divides", and note that "strictly divides" only makes sense for (prime) powers. It's technically a shorthand abuse of notation but makes it easy to remember.